# Need help on generating random words for a search bot VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

So i am trying to make a search bot that uses random words. I am using an increment value with Minimum of 2 and a Maximum of 30 for the number of searches to do at a time.

I was thinking something like this but it also seems like it would not be as good since it would not really generate a random string which would be a lot better:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SE As String
    SE = NumericUpDown1.Value
    Select Case SE
        Case "2"

    End Select
End Sub
```

If anybody could help me It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class and it's method [`Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) to create random numbers.

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim SE As String = rnd.Next(2, 31).ToString()
```

Note that  the random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same
 seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated.

So if you want to use a loop, you should not create the random instance in the loop but outside of it.

However, i'm not sure what kind of words you want to create. I doubt that you want numeric strings between "2" and"30" even if your code suggests it.

**Update** according to your comment

> The 2 and 30 are how many searches to do at a time, i want to
>    randomize the word(s) out of
>   lets say a list of 60-70 words

So i assume that you want  a random number(between 2-30)of random words from a list of strings:

```
Dim words = {"word 1", "word 2", "word 3", ".....", "word 60"}
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim howMany As Int32 = rnd.Next(2, 31)
Dim randomWords As New List(Of String)
For i As Int32 = 1 To howMany
    Dim nextRandomIndex = rnd.Next(0, words.Count)
    randomWords.Add(words(nextRandomIndex))
Next
```

Comment: The 2 and 30 are how many searches to do at a time, i mainly want the random or randomize i think it is to basically pick (a) word(s) out of lets say a list of 60-70 words then search for it automatically after you click the button. If that helps to explain it a bit more.

Comment: @JohnDunwoody: Can the words repeat (randomly)?

Comment: Now i'm starting to feel like a beginner with VB, now since i seem to have forgotten a lot of the stuff i have learned i have a few more things i could use help with. 1: How could i make the search words appear in a ListBox as separate strings? 2: Will that code you gave also change amount of words to gather depending on the value of the NumericUpDown control? Lastly how could i implement the code to search a search engine with the corresponding generated words in multiple instances?(That is what is mainly making me feel like beginner again.